# Angular 2 | How can i set the value of select box

Tags: angular

How can i set the value of select box when div is selected. I am using ngModel here but it's not working.

here's my sample.

somecomponent.html

```
<div class="form-group input-holder">
  <label class="col-lg-2">Storage type</label>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <select class="category" name="storagetype" [(ngModel)]="storageType">
      <option *ngFor="let value of values" [value]="value">{{ value }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

somecomponent.html

```
ngOnInit() {
this.storageId = this.storageEntryService.storages.slice();
this.subscription = this.storageEntryService.StartEditStorage.subscribe(
    (index: number) => {
      this.storageIdIndex = index;
      this.editedstorage = this.storageEntryService.getStorage(index);
        this.storageForm.setValue({
          storagetype: this.editedstorage.storagetype.toUpperCase()
        })
    }
  );  }
```

then

```
<!-- modal -->
<div class="md-modal md-effect-1" id="modal-1" [ngStyle]="{'visibility': showmodal === true ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}">
  <div class="md-content" [ngClass]="{'showmodalcss': showmodal === true}">
    <h3>Select Storage</h3>
    <div>
      <table class="table responsive table-striped">
        <thead class="bg-primary">
          <tr>
            <th>Storage ID</th>
            <th>Storage Type</th>
            <th>Lock</th>
            <th>Created By</th>
            <th>Created date</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let storages of storageId; let i = index" (click)="editItem(i)">
            <td>{{ storages.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ storages.storagetype }}</td>
            <td>{{ storages.islock }}</td>
            <td>{{ storages.createdby }}</td>
            <td>{{ storages.createddate }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button class="md-close" (click)="showmodal = false">Close me!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

what i want is everytime i click some storageid the value of select must be display. 2nd image show that it's not passing the data everytime some storage id is selected.
[image: When this storage id is Selected it will display the data for edit purposes.]

[image: highlight with yeloow shows that it's not passing the data on select element]

Comment: when selecting a storageId it will pass all data of my storages, but it seems it only not pass to select as value. my problem is how can i set the value of storage type. as my code abose somecompnent.ts i set the value and pass it on storageForm.

Comment: can you try like [selected] = "storageType == value" in the select box , also make sure If the value is not a string [ngValue]="..." must be used. [value]="..." only supports strings.

Comment: may data is in another object. im not setting default values here instead im gonna petch data of my object and display on select element as value's

Comment: are you setting the selected or the ngModal  item when your are clicking on the storage id

Comment: yes, im setting an object value to select for editing functionality.

Comment: where are you setting the ng modal ? can you post that bit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148973/discussion-between-jydon-mah-and-rahul-singh).